# Idling thread between curl_multi_perform

Tags: c++, multithreading, libcurl

I have an update thread which runs curl_multi_perform in a while loop in it. I want to make sure the thread doesn't just sit there and spin, so I'd like to throttle it to a few updates per second. This works fine, except for when doing file uploads or downloads on 10+ MB files, when curl_multi_perform has to be called pretty much continuously to get around the upload/download chunk limit.

Is there a way to poll if curl_multi_perform will need to be called right away again in the next update loop, or if it's okay to let the thread idle for ~100 ms? I thought curl_multi_wait would be used for this, but the thread seems to be spinning up the CPU while inside curl_multi_wait anyway, so that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Why not do something like `nextTime = now() + interval; do_task(); sleep(nextTime - now());` So if the job takes longer than `interval` the loop restarts right away, otherwise it sleeps a bit.

Comment: @slim Oh, no, it isn't that the job takes too long, it is that each time I call curl_multi_perform while uploading, it will send a chunk of data, which is capped at 16kb for uploads. If I only called perform ~10 times per second, I'd have a max bandwidth of 160 kbps. So what I would like is some way to know if I should idle the thread for ~100ms, or if I should run the next iteration right away, so I can send another chunk without waiting.

Comment: and that's what I've described. If `interval` is 1s, and `do_task` takes 1s then it will run again right away. If `do_task` takes 0.7s, then it will sleep 0.3s before running again.

Comment: curl can't see into the future, so you can never be sure of what's coming. If a packet comes the next millisecond, or if an outgoing socket gets writable in 10 milliseconds, curl wants to get called again. You can never *know* that there will be a gap in time as long as you have a transfer going.

Comment: @DanielStenberg so there is no method to find out if curl will want to be called again right away the next iteration, as in the case of chunking data? Or, alternately, if there is a download/upload in progress? Is the recommended implementation to make your own throttling, toggled off when a u/d is in progress?

Comment: The regular multi interface allows you to check if you should call curl_multi_perform() right away or how long to wait until you do it. But since you should call it when the sockets say so, you don't know when that will be.

Comment: @DanielStenberg is there such a thing as best practice on how to implement a continuous curl_multi update loop, to be run in parallel with the rest of the program without hogging the CPU? I've been trying to navigate the documentation, but all examples and use cases seem to assume a one-off request rather than a constant flow. Is that the intended use case?

Comment: One off or continuous makes no difference really, the API is the same. And no, it really does not hog the CPU - then you're doing something wrong or have an amazingly fast network.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Okay so, I may be a bit slow, but I'm not entirely keeping up here. We are talking about the example implementation at https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_multi_perform.html , right? To me (and again, I may be a bit slow, so I apologize if this is obvious), what this says is that I should idle the thread (sleep) when curl tells me there are no active file handles (if(maxfd == -1)), otherwise I should call the loop again and do another curl_multi_perform, yes?

Comment: That's for the edge case when it can't expose an underlying socket.

Comment: @DanielStenberg Okay, I must be really stupid. Could you point me to what you meant when you said "The regular multi interface allows you to check if you should call curl_multi_perform() right away or how long to wait until you do it"? Which function or variable will give me this information? Alternately, if I've completely missed some big obvious article in the documentation about this, I would be much obliged if you could link it to me

Comment: this is way, waaay, off what this question asked...

Answer (score 1):

I recommend `sleep_until` instead of `sleep_for` for your application:

```
using namespace std::chrono;
auto next = steady_clock::now() + milliseconds{10};
while(runUpdateThread)
{
    curl_multi_perform(mCurlHandle, &handleCount);

    /* handle call results */

    std::this_thread::sleep_until( next );
    next += milliseconds{10};
}
```

Now if the upload/download takes a long time, the `sleep_until` doesn't sleep at all.  This effectively gives you the *auto throttling* you are after.

Comment: You're right that sleep_until is more appropriate than sleep_for, and would be more consistent, but this was not the kind of throttling I was looking for. It is irrelevant how long the curl_multi_perform takes, what I wanted to know was whether there was a good way to decide when the thread idle should be shorter or longer, depending on how much available work there is, since the amount of work each loop can do is capped. Thus, if there is more work to be done after the loop ends, I want to idle for a short or no time. If there is no work to be done, I want to idle for a long time.

Answer (score 0):

So for future reference, what I ended up doing was just idling the thread 10ms every iteration. This effectively caps the up speed to 1.6 mbps when using the default value for CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE in curl.h. For faster speeds I guess I'd have to either up the CURL_MAX_WRITE_SIZE define, or idle the thread for a shorter time.

Rough pseudocode:

```
while(runUpdateThread)
{
    curl_multi_perform(mCurlHandle, &handleCount);

    /* handle call results */

    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds(10) );
}
```